# Empty revision after edit suggestion has been improved by two users

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, revisions-list, improve-edit

I just reviewed a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1526563) on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891539/weird-error-after-struct-to-struct-assignment). It turns out that apart from myself another user seemed to have improved the post while marking the original suggestion as not helpful.

The [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14891539/revisions) of said post now contains three revisions: The original (1), mine with the change to the title (2), and psubsee2003's with no content at all (3):

[image]

(Note that revisions 2 and 3 are both being expanded)

Shouldn't one of the (seemingly identical edits) have "won" so that only one additional revision shows up in the revision history? Is that a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) or [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)?

Comment: That's just wieird. It looks to be, as you say, a race that you "won" by 6 seconds. Psubsee would have made an identical edit to yourself.